# Add Splash Screen

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, plymouth

I want to get some splash screens of my own.  I am installing them from http://www.gnome-look.org/  I have no idea how to add them to the menu so that I can set it as a splash screen.  I just know that I get a tar.gz file.  Where do I put the file?

Answer (score 1):

Type in a terminal:

```
sudo thunar
```

Go in directory `/lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo`

There you can change the wallpaper at start (`wallpaper.png`) and the xubuntu logo (there are 2 logos)